# How to delete the last 3 lines of every 10 lines in a 100 line text file?

Tags: bash

Suppose my file is

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
6. f
7. g
8. h
9. i
10. j
    ...

I want my output to be

1. a
2. b
3. c
4. d
5. e
6. f
7. g

My file is 100 lines long, so the code has to essentially remove the last 3 lines in every 10 line chunk. I tried using the code below, but I couldn't get it to delete a range.

```sh
awk 'NR % 7 !=0' file.txt
```

Comment: Well, `NR` is the current line number. It counts from 1, ie. first line. Now write a condition with `NR` using mathematical operations, so that a condition is true, when the line number is "the last 3 lies in every 10 line chunk", and otherwise is false. How would you write such condition? awk has [many arithmetic operations](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Arithmetic-Ops.html) and [boolean operators](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Boolean-Ops.html)

Comment: KamilCuk has shamed me into not providing the answer for you with his good example.  However, I'll give you a hint, try this program: awk '{ print NR % 10, $0 }'

Comment: Using GNU `sed`, a one-liner:  `sed '8~10d; 9~10d; 10~10d' file.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awk's `NR` variable contains the line number starting with `1`. `NR - 1` is the line number starting with `0`.

The reminder of `NR - 1` divided by `10` is `0..6` for the first 7 lines of each 10-lines block and `7..9` for the last three.

The command is as simple as:

```
awk '(NR - 1) % 10 < 7' file.txt
```

Comment: Why not `NR%10<8`?

Comment: Because for the 10th line, `NR` is `10` and `NR % 10` is `0`. The 10th line must be removed but it is displayed because `10 % 0 < 8`. The same happens for lines 20, 30, 40 a.s.o.

Comment: Any trick using the reminder works only when the counting starts from `0` (or from a multiple of the divider). To make it start from `0` it's enough to subtract the first value from all values. If the outcome must include the original value then revert the adjustment at the end (it is not needed here).

Answer (score 0):

```sh
 awk '{if(NR % 10 < 8 && NR % 10 != 0) {print}}' file.txt
```

You need to mod 10 to skip some lines every 10, not mod 7.

Comment: Or you could try this:  awk ' NR % 10 < 8 && NR % 10 > 0 '  file.txt

Comment: Why would you test for `NR%10 != 0`? It happens for `NR=0`, `NR=10`,`20`,`30`… or when the input file is empty. It does not make sense to test it here.

Comment: @LéaGris, Yes, it does happen for those lines. (S)He does not want those lines. (S)He wants the last 3 lines of every 10 removed. That would be lines 8, 9 and 10.